# Xcode Краш приложения

Tags: xcode, objective-c, cocos2d

Всех приветствую!
xcode 5, делаю игрушку по мануалу(cocos2d), при добавлении следующего кода  приложение не запускается(до этого все хорошо)

```
_playerTank = [[JTPlayerTank alloc] initWithSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"tank2.png"] scene:self properties:nil];
    _playerTank.position = ccp(_winSize.width/2, _winSize.height/2);
    [self addChild:_playerTank z:50];
```

не имею опыта и знаний - проблему решить не могу.
есть идеи?
Спасибо

Comment: Лог краша неплохо было бы добавить еще

Comment: В 2013 вышла iOS 7 со Sprite Kit, мне кажется там меньше секса и не понятных крашей.

Comment: Deadkenny
2014-02-17 22:59:17.501 JustTanks[1038:70b] *** Assertion failure in -[CCTimerTargetSelector initWithTarget:selector:interval:repeat:delay:], /Users/alexnt/ios dev/Apps/JustTanks/JustTanks/libs/cocos2d/CCScheduler.m:193
2014-02-17 22:59:17.505 JustTanks[1038:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Signature not found for selector - does it have the following form? -(void) name: (ccTime) dt'
*** First throw call stack:

это подойдет?)

Comment: JTPlayerTank от кого унаследован проверьте?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по эксепшену, шедулер пытается вызвать селектор неправильной сигнатуры. На сколько я помню, шедулер может вызывать метод только с параметром, например, как подсказывает дебагер, (ccTime)dt.
Проверьте шедулеры в классе JTPlayerTank. Вызываемый шедулером метод должен иметь параметр (ccTime)dt